# What is this connector type (Segway e-Scooter charger)

Tags: connector, charger, power-connector

I'm doing a little research to, in the future, possibly replace my [Segway E110SE](https://nl-nl.segway.com/products/segway-escooter-e110se) e-Moped charger whenever it gives out or to possibly have a second one on hand to haul around to destinations. Whatever.

However, I'm having quite a hard time to find replacement chargers. I can't even find the 'original' one [at Segway](https://shop.segway.com/nl_nl/accessories.html) or [elsewhere on the web](https://www.google.com/search?q=nb-52d5-8d0); I found [one charger](http://www.fsp-powerland.com/index.php/productInfo/57.html) that may come close but it doesn't show the connector anywhere. Long story short: maybe if I know what the connector is called I can broaden my search efforts and maybe find some more suitable replacements/additions to my current charger.

The charger outputs 52.5V DC / 8A according to its label.

[image: Connector]
[image: Charger]

Comment: Unfortunately, that is probably a custom connector made specifically for Segway. Also note the extra 6 small pins on the bottom. This probably indicates that there is some sort of data connection between the scooter and charger which will prevent you from using a generic charger. Sorry, but you’re probably hosed.

Comment: Did you manage to find something? Im searching for it too and so are a lot of other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like a B110P connector, I am also try to find an extension cable for this. Or make one.
https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/1005004539077948.html

Comment: Now that we've found the (female) connector (maybe the male too?) it shouldn't be hard to make an extension cable.